# Creating a pop up window in Google Sheets in a cell has a value inputed

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, popupwindow

I found a apps script that is suppose to help with creating a pop up window when a range of cells have a value inputed. For the life of me I can not get it to work. All I want is for a range of cells to trigger a pop up window if text happens to be inputed into them. Any help would be appreciated.

```
function onEdit(e)
{  
  
  // Get the active sheet.
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  // Set the range that has to be checked for changes.
  var selectedRange = sheet.getRange("P1:P1500");

  // Get the active cell from the event obejct.
  var activeCell = e.range_;

  // Check if the active cell belongs to the range of interest. 
  // If yes, show a message box in the browser.
  if(rangeIntersect(activeCell, selectedRange)) 
  Browser.msgBox("CUSTOMER OWES MONEY!!");   
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the spreadsheet? The trigger is not being called because the cells of P are not being [edited by the user](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite) these are being edited by a formula.

Answer (score 1):

This this one, but make sure there is no other function with the same name:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  // Get the active sheet.
  var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  //var selectedRange = sheet.getRange("P1:P1500");
  var thisRow = e.range.getRow();
  var thisCol = e.range.getColumn();
  //Checks if the active cell/modified is within the range stated above
  if (thisRow >= 1 && thisRow <= 1500 && thisCol === 16) {
    Browser.msgBox("CUSTOMER OWES MONEY!!");
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This does work! Except I have discovered it won't work for what I had in the cells. I have an array formula that would generate text based on another cells input value. When that text appeared in P cells it did not trigger the pop up box. However if I just type into P cells (overwrite the formula) it does trigger it.

Comment: In that case, you'd have to change the ```function``` so it'd check this range every X minutes. This works when you add an ```Installable trigger```. Maybe, you should throw another question with the difficulty that you find along the way, should you decide to pursue it.

Comment: Possible to refer to the range being edited in the script. Something like:  `  var data = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange("Sheet1!A1:C6").getValues();` followed by the rest of the script? Not sure if it'll work but worth a try. More detail; https://spreadsheet.dev/reading-from-writing-to-range-in-google-sheets-using-apps-script